# DragAndDrop java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: java, drag-and-drop

I am learning Drag and Drop, but for every single example that I want to study, I get the folowing exception `java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot load system cursor: CopyDrop.32x32`. Does anyone know what is the meaning of this exception and how can I fix it? Even with this [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/dnd/DropDemoProject/src/dnd/DropDemo.java) I get that exception.

`java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot load system cursor: CopyDrop.32x32
    at sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.lazilyLoadDesktopProperty(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.getDesktopProperty(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.dnd.DragSource.load(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.dnd.DragSource.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.DragRecognitionSupport.mousePressedImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.DragRecognitionSupport.mousePressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI$Handler.mousePressed(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.awt.AWTException: Exception: class java.security.PrivilegedActionException null occurred while loading: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101\lib\images\cursors\cursors.properties
    at java.awt.Cursor.loadSystemCustomCursorProperties(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Cursor.getSystemCustomCursor(Unknown Source)
    ... 39 more
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.DragRecognitionSupport.mousePressedImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.DragRecognitionSupport.mousePressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI$Handler.mousePressed(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mousePressed(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: failed to load system cursor: DnD.Cursor.CopyDrop : cannot load system cursor: CopyDrop.32x32
    at java.awt.dnd.DragSource.load(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.dnd.DragSource.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    ... 35 more`

I have a minimal example ,I get same exception.

```
    public DragAndDrop() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    TransferHandler transfer = new TransferHandler("text");

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setDragEnabled(true);
    textArea.setTransferHandler(transfer);
}
```

Comment: Post the entire stacktrace.

Comment: Is this a Java Swing question? Can you put a minimal example of what you have tried _inside_ the question?

Comment: Searching Google I find a lot of bug reports on this. Perhaps your OS and JDK version is relevant.

Comment: @E_net4 I have tried the example that I linked, and for every example that is about DragAndDrop, I get same exception. Yes is Java Swing

Comment: @GenDarme my OS is Windows 10, and jdk version is jdk1.7.0_80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem !
I had installed jre1.8.0_101, and I upgraded to jre1.8.0_111.
If anyone have this issue about DragAndDrop, make sure u have latest version of jre.